# To read TMP adc sensor data over mcp3008 (spi) with the customised driver on raspberry pi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver

I am writing a mcp3008 device driver without iio support for learning purpose. I have followed this link for [pin connections](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/analogue-sensors-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/).

I have attached my [source code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1PHxtbOmCMpNk5aY21RdXdTOWc).

Driver is successfully bound to spi subsys, dmesg is as

```
[    9.053293] bus: 'platform': driver_probe_device: matched device soc:audio with driver bcm2835_AUD0
[    9.053316] bus: 'platform': really_probe: probing driver bcm2835_AUD0 with device soc:audio
[    9.103796] driver: 'bcm2835_AUD0': driver_bound: bound to device 'soc:audio'
[    9.103843] bus: 'platform': really_probe: bound device soc:audio to driver bcm2835_AUD0
[   11.703933] systemd-journald[116]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   13.170530] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   14.801684] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[   16.057113] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:3 across:1773568k SSFS
[   26.739940] random: crng init done
[   66.338696] bus: 'spi': driver_probe_device: matched device spi0.1 with driver aartyaa_mcp3008
[   66.338720] bus: 'spi': really_probe: probing driver aartyaa_mcp3008 with device spi0.1
[   66.338831] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: aaartyaa came in probe, master dev = spi0
[   66.338845] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_device_alloc : devres is allocated
[   66.338855] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_device_alloc : dev is added to devres
[   66.338864] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_probe : trasefer buffer is ready
[   66.338871] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_probe : initing spi msg
[   66.338881] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_probe : creating sysfs for mcp3008
[   66.338912] driver: 'aartyaa_mcp3008': driver_bound: bound to device 'spi0.1'
[   66.338946] bus: 'spi': really_probe: bound device spi0.1 to driver aartyaa_mcp3008
```

I have connected TMP36 to channel1 of mcp3008. I am trying to read analog value in a sysfs entry(/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi0.1/aartyaa_mcp3008).

I have tried with giving 3V3 to channel1 as well. But I am not able to read adc value. dmesg is as =>

```
[  101.311640] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_aartyaa_show_data
[  101.311807] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_conversion : ret = 0
[  101.311822] aartyaa_mcp3008 spi0.1: mcp3008_aartyaa_show_data : ret = 0
```

How can I read a TMP36 adc value over mcp3008 using this driver.
Any help will be appreciated and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

regret for inconvenience.
CE and deferential pins were wrongly connected on the board.

Driver works fine as it was expected.

Thanks.